# Why was my question closed as "Primarily Opinion Based"?

Tags: discussion, support

This [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36806/crossed-arms-in-body-language?noredirect=1#comment142632_36806) was closed as Primarily Opinion Based. What does that mean on a site about skepticism? On what grounds was my question a POB one? How could it be improved and made on-topic according to the site standards?

Comment: Why was my question modified?

Comment: The reasoning was provided in the edit comment: "Haven't heard anyone use POB as an acronym. Focussed to one question: What does it mean? If you want it to be about YOUR question, please edit to make that clear in the title too." When you edited it back to be about your question, I removed the generic part, so as not to trick others into thinking the answer was generic.

Comment: @Oddthinking - POB is a common acronym in other SE sites, maybe not here. Anyway I am not surprised by the unwelcoming spirit of the site.

Comment: I'll invite you to take a break and then come back and have another look at how you were treated. There was no malice, no rudeness. You weren't ignored. Quite some effort was made to deal with both your first question and your meta-question including making them answerable and providing an answer, for the second. POB isn't a common term here so that was quietly fixed for you. I understand you disagree with the reasoning, but that's not unwelcoming. I hope you will come back and we can get your question fixed up and answered.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I suspect it means that, before answering, I am going to have to form an opinion on what "defensive attitude" means, and my opinion of that might be different from the next person's opinion.

The question could be improved by being more specific, so that it is less based on that opinion and more on some concrete fact which were investigating.

Comment: I said: "Crossed arms are generally believed to indicate a defensive attitude, a sign of closure towards other person/s." Does this introduction look really unclear? Plus the  explanation from the extract adds more details. What else?

Comment: @JoeBlack can you not see how that very definition is "Primarily Opinion Based". There is undoubtedly a cultural effect there too.

Comment: So what? is a site about skepticism biased against possible cultural issues? And what culture is the site about specifically?

Comment: @JoeBlack It might help for you to read [this](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) to discover what this site is about.

Comment: I 110% agree on the "hostility" point. Thanks and Goodbye.